Как в Qt сделать размер шрифтов такой-же как в MS Visio
Делаю графический редактор.
Элемент "текст" представлен в виде переопределённого QGraphicsTextItem. При задании размера шрифту через setPointSizeF() заметил несоответствие размеров букв и цифр. К примеру в Visio если для текста выбрать размер шрифта 9пт то размер его заглавной буквы или цифры будет равен 2.3мм, в то время в Qt если я задаю setPointSizeF(9) их размер равен 3.17мм, что соответствует данным перевода пт в мм. Получается так что в Visio размеры шрифтов меньше чем в Qt примерно в (0.7-0.8) в зависимости от выбранного размера и связанно это с тем что в Visio и Qt само понятие размера шрифта различаются. Работа с разными свойствами QFont не дали результата. Есть ли способ настройки размеров шрифта чтобы привести его к размеру в Visio. Пока что придумал только после выставления размера применять к объекту QGraphicsTextItem::setScale(0.XX)

Проверь шрифты, одинаковы ли

@evo Шрифты и там и там выставлены Tahoma. При выставлении другого шрифта и там и там, результат тот же (в Visio размер заглавной буквы меньше чем в Qt)

Так, стоп, перечитал вопрос, а что вс не устраивает в 3.17мм? Это же правильный размер.  2.3 millimeter = 6.5196850394 point

@evo меня то как раз устраивает. Мне надо чтобы шрифт был такого же или очень близкого размера в мм как это сделано в Visio. А там если 9 шрифт выбираем то заглавная буква этого шрифта равна не 3.17, а 2.3.
Я пока что придумал способ без использования setScale().
1пт теперь считаю условно равным 0.1мм. Таким образом если мне нужен шрифт высотой 3.17мм я просто беру и выставляю шрифту в Qt размер 3.17 * 10 = 31.7пт. При распечатке на лист А4  с заданием нужных настроек в QPrinter всё по идее должно иметь правильные пропорции. Хотя данный способ мне кажется костыльным

@evo нашёл ещё что в висио хоть и написано что размеры используются в пт, по факту там используется px. И вот как раз то на то и выходит, 1px = 0.26мм, поэтому шрифты в висио выглядят меньше. Непонятно или ошибка локализации или что-то ещё. Продолжу своим методом делать в общем
